# Windows 10 Pro update: Unsupported Disk Layout for UEFI Firmware. Fix without reinstall?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, uefi, mbr, gpt

I have a Windows 10 Pro installation that was upgraded from a previous Windows 8 install. When installing the latest Windows 10 upgrade, the update fails with the error "Unsupported Disk Layout for UEFI Firmware".

I understand this is because i have MBR partitions and not a GPT partition table. All the guides I've found tell me I have to reinstall Windows from scratch after repartitioning the drive.

Is there a way to convert the partitions and keep the installed copy of Windows 10 working so I don't have to reinstall?

Comment: [Windows 10 has a built-in tool that will perform the migration from MBR to GPT.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt).  You might want to be more specific than "the lastest Windows 10 upgrade" due to the fact, that could mean any number of different versions, and that isn't as desciptive as you might think.  However, every version of Windows 10 supports MBR, so it would helpful to indicate how you are attemptiong to install the upgrade (I doubt it's through Windows Update).

Comment: But does running MBR2GPT solve the issue? If so, why isn't it mentioned elsewhere or even by Microsoft?

Comment: It is not mentioned by Microsoft because it's only required if you want to perform the conversion to GPT.  **You have only asked, in your question body, how the migration from MBR to GPT without dataloss can be performed.**  You might want to verify your partition type isn't already GPT.  This particular problem is not new, and can happen, even when the partition type is already GPT.  **Before you proceed you should, provide us with all relevant information, to help you solve the underline issue and that is NOT how you convert to GPT from MBR witout dataloss.**  Proceed with caution.